# How do I use TextField with suggestions for WatchOS SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos

Currently there is no suggestion input for TextField.

I found an extension to use TextField with suggestions on WatchOS but **this one is not working on a view which navigated with NavigationLink**

Here is the wrapper code;

```
 import Foundation
 import SwiftUI

extension View {
    typealias StringCompletion = (String) -> Void
    
    func presentInputController(withSuggestions suggestions: [String], completion: @escaping StringCompletion) {
        WKExtension.shared()
            .visibleInterfaceController?
            .presentTextInputController(withSuggestions: suggestions,
                                        allowedInputMode: .allowEmoji) { result in
                
                guard let result = result as? [String], let firstElement = result.first else {
                    completion("")
                    return
                }
                completion(firstElement)
            }
        
    }
}
```

I'm looking forward to your **suggestions** too :))